# determin the number of letters in a word?

Tags: python

hi i want  a built in function or a method to determine the number of letters in words the vowels and constants

I know in php there is strlen is there an equivalent to it in python?

I tried to use sum but it did not work

```
def num_of_letters(word)
  (str)->int
'''


'''
sum(word)
```

I am a newbie in programming   any help and explanation would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: this might be a good place to look: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count *only* vowels and consonants, you could try something like this:

```
s = "hello world"

print sum(c.isalpha() for c in s)
```

---

To count vowels and consonants individually, you could try this:

```
s = "hello world"

print sum(c in "aAeEiIoOuU" for c in s)  # count vowels

print sum(c.isalpha() and c not in "aAeEiIoOuU" for c in s)  # count consonants
```

---

Of course, to obtain the overall length of your string (including spaces etc.), you would do this:

```
s = "hello world"

print len(s)
```

Comment: This is a nice and easy way to do it, so +1, although there can be problems when you try to count vowels and consonants separately and you have tremas and accents and such.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function [len](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/built-in-funcs.html#l2h-45)

For example:

```
len(word)
```

Comment: Upvoted. They asked for the equivalent of `strlen`. That's `len`. I don't know what they're saying about vowels and consonants.

Comment: "i want a built in function or a method to determine the number of letters in words the vowels and constants"

Answer (score 0):

```
def num_of_letters(word):
    """tuple of (vowels, consonants) count in `word`"""
    vowel_count = len([l for l in word.lower() if l in 'aeiou'])
    return vowel_count, len(word) - vowel_count
```

Comment: the question is Two function definitions are saved in the same file: A function count_vowels has one parameter, . A function count_consonants has one parameter, a word, and returns the number of consonants in that word. To determine the number of letters in a word, write a one-line body for the following function that calls both count_vowels and count_consonants: def count_letters(word): ''' (str) -> int

Return the number of letters .
>>> count_letters('hello')
5

'''
# Writ the one-line function body that belongs here.
my attempt was like this return count_vowels(word)+count_consonants(word)